# Google map auto zoom with multiple markers in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

directive.js:

```
.directive('map', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      onCreate: '&'
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493, -89.381388),
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map($element[0], mapOptions);

        $scope.onCreate({map: map});

        // Stop the side bar from dragging when mousedown/tapdown on the map
        google.maps.event.addDomListener($element[0], 'mousedown', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        });
      }

      if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        initialize();
      } else {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<map on-create="mapCreated(map)" data-tap-disabled="true"></map>
```

controller.js:

```
//Map controller
$scope.mapCreated = function (map) {
    $scope.map = map;
    $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude1, longitude1));
    createMarker(latitude1, longitude1, icon1);
    createMarker(latitude2, longitude2, icon2);             

    //Create marker
    var createMarker = function (lat, long, icon) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
        });
    }
};
```

Let's say "latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2, icon1 and icon2" has been initialized.

Nothing went wrong with my code, but it didn't zoom out the map to show all the markers. I did some research before but I'm not found the suitable answer. Thanks for help.

Comment: Thanks but it still not working.

Comment: You have the problem il local when you run ionic serve, in device or both?

Comment: both, device and browser. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to disable `data-tap` 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/ for allow googlemaps handle tap event.

```
<ion-view>
...
<ion-content scroll="false">
    <map on-create="mapCreated(map)" data-tap-disabled="true"></map>
</ion-content>
...
</ion-view>
```

Comment: thank you, I'm already tried put the (data-tap-disabled="true") in my code but it still didn't worked. Nothing changed, my google map still not zoom out or zoom in to show all the markers.

Comment: That's weird, have you seen this ionic exemple ? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-maps. You must disable scroll too.

Comment: yes, already seen it. almost my code is same like that, but that example didn't show multiple markers.